# for how many integers does there exist a polynomial function

Tags: calculus

For how many integer values of $b$ does there exist a polynomial function with integer coefficients
such that $f(2) = 2010$ and $f(b) = 8$?

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $b - a$ always divides $f(b) - f(a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If f is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and a and b are integers, then a - b always divides
f(a)−f(b)

that is, $\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{a-b}$ = k  ; k is an integer

Let a=2

hence,  $\frac{2010 - 8}{2-b}$ = k

$\frac{2002}{2-b}$ = k

This implies, b =   $\frac{2k-2002}{k}$

All the values of k which satisfies the above condition and make b an integer are our solution.